# PyQt: How to connect automatically added buttons

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

The programm I'm trying to write adds a button for each element in a list

```
    for elem in add_new:
        counter = add_new.index(elem)
        name = add_new_names[counter]

        self.button = QPushButton(name)
        self.button.setObjectName('button_' + str(name))
        self.button.setFixedWidth(200)
        self.button.setFixedHeight(200)
        self.stacked_layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.mygroupbox.setLayout(self.stacked_layout)

        self.scroll.setWidget(self.mygroupbox)
```

This works, but now I want to connect those buttons to an event/function. If I add

```
self.button.clicked.connect(self.clickevent)
```

it executes the function (obviously) no matter what button is pressed. Is there a way to connect automatically added buttons to different functions/events?

EDIT:
To provide more code

```
class AppDemo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.first_time = "True"

        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.drop_label = ImageLabel()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.drop_label)

        self.myform = QHBoxLayout()
        self.mygroupbox = QGroupBox('selected pdf files')

        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setFixedHeight(300)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.scroll)

        self.stacked_layout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if self.find_pdf(event.mimeData()):
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.find_pdf(event.mimeData()):
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        add_new.clear()
        add_new_names.clear()
        urls = self.find_pdf(event.mimeData())
        if urls:
             for url in urls:
                self.path = url.toLocalFile()
                self.file_name = QFileInfo(self.path)
                self.filename = self.file_name.baseName()
                link_list.append(self.path)
                title_list.append(self.filename)
                list_of_links.append(self.path)
                add_new.append(self.path)
                add_new_names.append(self.filename)
            event.accept()

            self.button_creating()
         else:
            event.ignore()

    def button_creating(self):
        for elem in add_new:
            counter = add_new.index(elem)
            name = add_new_names[counter]
            self.button = QPushButton(name)
            self.button.setObjectName('button_' + str(name))
            self.button.setFixedWidth(200)
            self.button.setFixedHeight(200)
            self.stacked_layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.mygroupbox.setLayout(self.stacked_layout)

        self.scroll.setWidget(self.mygroupbox)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.clickevent)

    def find_pdf(self, mimedata):
        urls = list()
        db = QMimeDatabase()
        for url in mimedata.urls():
            mimetype = db.mimeTypeForUrl(url)
             if mimetype.name() == "application/pdf":
                 urls.append(url)
        return urls

    def clickevent(self):
        print(self.button.text())

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
demo = AppDemo()
demo.showMaximized()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Provide a complete minimal working example of your code and I can help

Comment: I edited the question to add more code

Comment: @monaghans_creed Creating a new group of buttons every time the urls change is an odd approach. It would be a lot simpler to use a list-widget.

Comment: I never came across the list-widget until now. I see your point, its way easier! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are looking for the function `self.sender()`.. With `self.sender()` you get to the button that was pressed. especially useful if you have many buttons, all call the same function and you want to know which button has been pressed.
then you can use `pressed_btn = self.sender()` and access all functions of `QPushButton`. Here i have an example to explain:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        for i in range(10):
            button = QPushButton(str(i), self)
            button.setObjectName('button_' + str(i))
            button.clicked.connect(self.test)
            layout.addWidget(button)

    def test(self):
        button = self.sender()
        print(f'Button Object name: {button.objectName()}\nButton Text: {button.text()}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    example = Example()
    example.show()
    app.exec()
```

**Output when i clicked button 0:**
[image: When i clicked button 0]